# UserForm Submit Button to Calculate Dynamic Formula + Insert Row

Tags: vba, dynamic, formula

I use following code to transfer my userform data (from textboxes to respective cell values in row A2) which works fine for me as i want the data to be pushed down when added:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim emptyRow As Long

'Validation
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("RawData").Range("A:A"), 
Me.TextBox1.Value) = False Then
    MsgBox "Ticket Does Not Exist", vbCritical
End If

'Determine emptyRow
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

'Transfer information
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WOTracker")
    .Cells(2, 1).EntireRow.Insert
    .Cells(2, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
    .Cells(2, 5).Value = TextBox2.Value
    .Cells(2, 2).Value = TextBox3.Value
    .Cells(2, 3).Value = TextBox4.Value
    .Cells(2, 6).Value = TextBox5.Value
    .Cells(2, 7).Value = ComboBox1.Value
    .Cells(2, 8).Value = ComboBox2.Value
    .Cells(2, 9).Value = TextBox8.Value
    .Cells(2, 4).Value = TextBox9.Value
    End With

'Formatting
Dim dDate As Date
dDate = DateSerial(Month(Date), Day(Date), Year(Date))
TextBox2.Value = Format(TextBox2.Value, "mm/dd/yy")
dDate = TextBox2.Value

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WOTracker")
    Sheets("WOTracker").Range("A2:Z2").Font.Bold = False
    Sheets("WOTracker").Range("A2:Z2").Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    End With
End Sub
```

In the same sheet, there is column L where i would like to calculate the difference between current date and the date mentioned in column E2 (in # of days) and i would like this to be dynamic so when a new line of data is added to row A2, this formula is applied in L2 while maintaining the formula in the rest of the column L for the data that will be pushed down.

I have tried copy/pastespecial and it doesnt work....

I hope this makes sense.

Would really appreciate assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I would make some organizational changes to your code first

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim emptyRow As Long

'Validation
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("RawData").Range("A:A"), 
Me.TextBox1.Value) = False Then
    MsgBox "Ticket Does Not Exist", vbCritical
End If

'Transfer information
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WOTracker")
    .Cells(2, 1).EntireRow.Insert
    'Determine emptyRow
    emptyRow = .Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
    'changed from WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1 so we can retrieve last  
    'row in column L
    .Cells(2, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
    .Cells(2, 5).Value = TextBox2.Value
    .Cells(2, 2).Value = TextBox3.Value
    .Cells(2, 3).Value = TextBox4.Value
    .Cells(2, 6).Value = TextBox5.Value
    .Cells(2, 7).Value = ComboBox1.Value
    .Cells(2, 8).Value = ComboBox2.Value
    .Cells(2, 9).Value = TextBox8.Value
    .Cells(2, 4).Value = TextBox9.Value
    .Range("L2:L" & emptyRow) = "=DAYS(TODAY(),$E$2)"
End With

'Formatting <- Might consider deleting the lines containing dDate since it's never 
               'used
Dim dDate As Date
dDate = DateSerial(Month(Date), Day(Date), Year(Date))
TextBox2.Value = Format(TextBox2.Value, "mm/dd/yy")
dDate = TextBox2.Value

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WOTracker")
    Sheets("WOTracker").Range("A2:Z2").Font.Bold = False
    Sheets("WOTracker").Range("A2:Z2").Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    End With
End Sub
```

The line `.Range("L2:L" & emptyRow) = "=DAYS(TODAY(),$E$2)"` will calculate the difference in days between the current date and the date in cell E2 for every cell in column L.

If, instead, what you wanted is for each line to subtract from today with respect to it's row number, just change

`.Range("L2:L" & emptyRow) = "=DAYS(TODAY(),$E$2)"`

To

`.Range("L2") = "=DAYS(TODAY(),$E$2)"`

And the insert operation will update the formula automatically.